# My create react app starter kit wont continue to create the app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to create a new react app with the npx cra but it has frozen at this section

[image: s]

Comment: it is probably because of slow internet connection. If not, you can try running `npm cache clean --force` and then create again

Answer (score 0):

I See your Question here and i know the answer!
So what happens in the cmd is that while you are installing something, if you select anywhere else while it is installing, it pauses the process, to continue simply press `Enter` on your keyboard, this should resume your process!